Different deployment manager resource name / managed resource name
I'm putting together a Google Cloud deployment manager solution. It's all fine, works great.
However.
I need to name different types of resources the same.
For example, I'd like to have a compute subnetwork, and a kubernetes cluster named "joe".
The Google Cloud API provides a property for the name of the API resource, so I tried this:
resources:
  - type: compute.v1.subnetwork
    name: subnet-joe
    properties:
      name: joe
      #...
  - type: gcp-types/container-v1beta1:projects.locations.clusters
    name: k8s-joe
    properties:
      cluster:
        name: joe
        subnetwork: $(ref.subnet-joe.name)
        #...

Since I need to name the deployment manager resources differently, so I prefix them with something that hints at their type. This way they are unique.
Unfortunately it doesn't matter how I set properties.name / properties.cluster.name, it has no effect. The GKE cluster and the subnet are always created with names matching their deployment manager resource name.
Is there any way to manage resources with names different from the deployment manager resource name?
In the example above, I'd like both the GKE cluster and compute subnet be created as "joe".
Is this even possible? How?
Thank you in advance.

That is right, and your resource name is utilized by the deployment manager to create an underlying google cloud resource. But what if you want each managed resource with different names?
This property.name property in each resource definition serves as the actual name for a managed resource in both subnet and GKE cluster.
In order to have GKE cluster and subnet created with name joe yet still have unique names within the deployment manager configuration, then separate the deployment manager resource name from the managed resource name.
